# Group and Subgroup Orders

Tags: group-theory

If G is a finite group with fewer than 100 elements and G has subgroups of orders 10 and 25, what is the order of G?  Please, explain your answer.

Comment: Is G abelian? Whether it is abelian or not, 2| o(G) and 25|o(G).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the answer has to be $50$ and only $50$; for, since $G$ has a subgroup of order $25$, it follows from Lagrange's theorem that $25 \mid \vert G \vert$, where $\vert G \vert$ is the order of $G$.  Likewise $10 \mid \vert G \vert$, whence $2 \mid \vert G \vert$.  Since $(2, 25) = 1$, that is, $2$ and $25$  are relatively prime, we must have $2 \times 25 = 50 \mid \vert G \vert$.  Since $\vert G \vert < 100$, it follows that  $\vert G \vert = 50$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***